# Rewrite Rule for Redirecting Transparently to Subfolder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I wish to write a rewrite rule for apache so that a request such as `http://www.domain.com/subfolder1` would redirect to `http://www.domain.com/subfolder2`.
This should happen transparently (i.e: without the url changing in the browser) and all subsequent url requests or links should be redirected to the new subfolder (subfolder2).
Is this possible and how?

Currently I have this rewrite rule which does redirect to subfolder2  but by clicking any link all requests are forwarded to the root path. i.e. `www.domain.com`. e.g Any link that points to link.php when I have this url (`www.domain.com/subfolder1`) open is redirected to `www.domain.com/link.php` while it should go to `www.domain.com/subfolder2/link.php`.

```
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent


Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^subfolder1?$ /subfolder2/ [P,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^subfolder1(/.*|)$ /subfolder2$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Transparent is when you don't want to do external redirect and change URL in browser. But if you want full redirect then add `R` flag. (Edited my answer)

Comment: I have not added the R flag but it still changes the URL in the browser to subfolder2

Comment: You earlier commented: `Currently it shows www.domain.com/subfolder1/link.php in the browser` I'm confused now. Does it change URL in browser?

Comment: Yes sorry, I messed up my earlier comment. I meant it shows www.domain.com/subfolder2/link.php while it should show www.domain.com/subfolder1/link.php

Comment: Without `R` flag URL should not change in browser unless you certain other rules in your .htaccess. Post your complete .htaccess in your question so that I can investigate. Also tell me if you are using some CMS framework which can change this behavior.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the remaining htaccess file

Comment: Ok saw that. You need to comment this line first: `RewriteRule ^subfolder1?$ /subfolder2/ [P,L]` Also tell me you're using some CMS or framework or if you any other .htaccess in your sub directories.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36039/discussion-between-mr-abbasi-and-anubhava)