# How to show only the domain.com not sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop-1.6

Hi I have installed prestashop in a sub-folder

www.mydomain.com/store  so the visitors have to enter the whole url to acces the prestashop.  I dont want prestashop to be in the root domain.

I found this rule for htaccess and works well

```
RewriteEngine on` 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.ee$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prestashop_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prestashop_subdir/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.ee$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ prestashop_subdir/index.php [L]
```

so now with this settings my visitors access the store using www.mydomain.com (they redirected to the sub-folder)

BUT on the addres bar appear (they see) www.mydomain.com/store

I just want that my visitors access www.mydomain.com   access the store automatically, but dont see the store subfolder  on the address bar. (where the prestashop is installed)

example:

www.mydomain.com  (visitor enter on address bar)
they be redirected to the store so can access it
but on the url  they can still see www.mydomain.com

PD. I copied the htaccess and index.php  from prestashop sub-folder installation to the domain (www.mydomain.com)

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384618/rewrite-rule-for-redirecting-transparently-to-subfolder

Comment: No its not the same.

Comment: Similar scenario i need the shopping cart installed on subdirectory to point to main domain and do not show domain.com/sub_folder on the url. Only domain,com should be see on the address bar of the browser

Comment: Have you acces to your vhosts configuration ? If yes, you can make your document root as your subdirectory. You have to change the URL from Prestashop like this : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/prestashop-15/change-site-url-in-database

Comment: You need to change the base URI at the prestashop URL config to /